# Whom is bharata referring "queen mothers" Or "raajadaaraaH" here?

Tags: ramayana, rama, sita, bharata

In
Yudhakand-127-3,

> Let bards well-versed in singing praises and Puranas (containing
> ancient legends, cosmogony etc.) as also all panegyrists, all those
> proficient in the use of musical instruments, courtesans all collected
> together, the **queen-mothers**, ministers, army-men and their wives,
> brahmanas accompanied by Kshatriyas (members of fighting class),
> leaders of guilds of traders and artisans, as also their members, come
> out to see the moon-like countenance of Rama."

Also are they possibly other wives of shri rama?

Comment: Shri Rama have only one wife 'Janki' also called as 'Sita'.